# Bash script with kill command

Tags: linux, process, pid, kill

If I try to kill a process in bash script it returns me the following error:
: arguments must be process or job IDs

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=`cat /var/www/html/pid.txt`
kill -SIGKILL $PID
```

Comment: I've tried kill -9 $PID still same error

Comment: What is result of `echo $PID`

Comment: 2100. The PID..

Comment: PID=`cat /var/www/html/pid.txt`
echo "kill -9 $PID"
returns kill -9 2100

Comment: Does 2100 exist as a process ID?

Comment: Yes, the command works if I execute by myself in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

It acts like `kill` is getting a non-numerical value.  If the process ID just doesn't exist, you get a different error (no such process).

I would look at the text file itself.  Make sure there aren't any special characters and that the PID is purely numerical.

Try something like this:

```
kill -9 $(cat /var/www/html/pid.txt | sed -e 's/[^0-9]\+//g')
```

If the process just doesn't exist, I'd expect an error like this:

```
bash: kill: (2100) - No such process
```